# W3C validation of css sprite back button?

Tags: onclick, css-sprites, w3c-validation

How can I make my css sprite back button validate through W3C?  Here is my code to call the button.

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)"><div class="icon-backbtn"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the below code to pass W3C validation and still using CSS Sprites.

```
<a id="icon-backbtn" title="Back" href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a `<div>` as a child of an `<a>`, use an `<img src="..."/>` instead.

**EDIT:**

If you have a spritesheet, then simply add `display:block;` for the anchor and it will behave just like a div.

Comment: can't use img src= because I'm using css sprites.

Comment: Updated my reply to provide a solution

Comment: could you give me an example about what your talking about?

Comment: <style>a { display: block; width: 10px; height: 10px; background: #000; }</style> <a href="#"></a> will render a black, 10px square link.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a CSS Sprite, I would suggest placing the `<a>` inside the `<div>` (*proper way to do it*) and add some css:

**HTML**

```
<div class="icon-backbtn">
  <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" title="Go Back"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-backbtn a {
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

The CSS sets the link to be a block element, thus occupying the width and height of the div. The remaining styles are to prevent the regular link behavior for texts, since you are using an image.

Comment: Just updated the answer to be have a clickable HREF by moving the javascript code from the onclick to the href.

Comment: Added the new javascript version and it's still not clickable...  Frustrating.